# .htaccess - .html redirect to /

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I am really new to this forum, it's my first post but I already read a lot.
But I didn't find any solution for my problem.

I will do the following via my `htaccess`:

301 redirect from every url of my site with the ending .html to /.

An example:

`www.xy.de/70.html` should be redirected to `www.xy.de/70/`

I already tried this code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is confusing. It mixes apache and nginx http servers...

Answer (score 1):

This should work for WordPress:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn`t work. At the moment, my htaccess looks like this:

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I still get a 404:

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>

# END WordPress

Answer (score 1):

Try the following htaccess mate ,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn`t work. Wordpress sents me everytime to a 404 when I test it. I already deactivate all plugins ...